# Emacs: `C-h k` is undefined

Tags: emacs

I am new to EMACS. I want to know the command bound with `C-x f`, so I type `C-h k`. But it won't work ,and shows me `C-h k is undefined`.

And my EMACS version is **26.0.90**.

Comment: What happens if you type M-x describe-key (which is the command you would expect to be bound to C-h k)?

Comment: Do you see that problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report the problem. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit code.

Comment: I just mistake `C-h k` and `C-h C-k`. I have learn the difference between them from the tutorial. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

"Answer" because I don't have 50 rep to ask in "comment".

Welcome to Emacs!

Thank you for your version info.  There are other questions which are valuable to the effort to help you.  For example:

- What OS are you using?
- Are you using a gui or a terminal?
- If terminal, which terminal?
- Are there errors in the *Messages* buffer on startup?
- Do you see the same problem if you start with "emacs -q"?
- Do you see the same problem if you start with "emacs -Q"?

One option you have would be to jump into the emacs chat room at  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17392/scratch

EDIT:
You may have a problem with C-h being a delete - see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey

To route around, the important help commands are:

```
C-h k -> M-x describe-key
C-h f -> M-x describe-function
C-h v -> M-x describe-variable
C-h a -> M-x apropos-command
C-h i -> M-x info
```

Comment: Thanks, I just mistake `C-h k` and `C-h C-k`.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the following figure: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ZRg.png)

You can see a key sequence C-h k

Otherwise, Look at what you are。